# RED5 Service is not visible in service.msc list

Tags: service, localhost, red5

Here the steps that I have followed.

- Installed JDK
- set the jre path
- Installation of RED5:
- Run set-up file

  - Default directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Red5.
  - IP Address Enter = 127.0.0.1
  - Port 5080
- Run RED5 service

  - Run Start > Programs > RED5 > Start RED5

When I am checking whether RED5 service is running or not in services.msc No Service is there..

[image]

at  http://localhost:5080/  it is showing webpage is not available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The windows service build is in flux while we switch from the Tanuki software wrapper to an open source implementation; Apache Daemon.